# Problem: \$\frac{4s + 2}{s(s-1)(s+2)} \$ Expectation of Root Locus Asymptote. (Control Systems)

Tags: rf, control-system, bode-plot, state-space

My transfer function is \$\frac{4s + 2}{s(s-1)(s+2)} \$

Given that there are 3 poles and 1 zeroes, the amount of loci going to infinity is 3-1 = 2 loci = r. I calculated where the centroid of the asymptotes should be begin. The equation is the (sum of poles - sum of zeroes)/r = location of centroid on real axis. The centroid location I got was **-.25**, so I can't understand why MATLAB plotted the root locus otherwise. Given that there are 3 poles, there are to be 3 asymptotes. (1 on the real axis and 2 going off the opposite direction.) I illustrated the supposed asymptotes in **black** in the following image. 
[image]
My problem is that the calculated asymptotes do not match up with my expectations. My calculated asymptotes are clearly not what MATLAB has calculated. Why and how so? I also did an angle computation using the formula (2q + 1)/r.

Comment: "do not match up with my expectations" and those expectations are.....?

Answer (score 1):

The angle the asymptotes make with the real-axes is \$\frac{(2 k+1)\pi}{2} \$. The denominator is the number of finite poles minus the number of finite zeros (\$3-1\$). This turns out as \$\frac{\pi}{2}\$ and \$\frac{3 \pi}{2}\$.

Because of one finite zero, one of the loci ends up at that zero. Only the other two go off to \$\infty\$.

[image]